# How do I add a bullet point in front of a text binding in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, decorator

I have the following abbreviated for simplicity

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding enumerableList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding displayName, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

How can I get it so that my TextBox shows a bullet point in front of the text bound to it? Desired format:

- List item 1
- List item 2

Comment: Have you considered modifying the the displayName property to prepend a bullet character to the front of the value before returning?  Or making a a ValueConverter do to that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the [`BulletDecorator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.bulletdecorator(v=vs.110).aspx) with the TextBlock. Example:

```
    <BulletDecorator>
      <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
        <Ellipse Height="10" Width="10" Fill="Blue"/>
      </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding displayName, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </BulletDecorator>
```

Comment: Alternatively, if I wanted to switch to numbers, letters, or roman numerals, is there something similar without adding it to my actual text string?

Comment: Use FlowDocument  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.list.aspx